# Rounding to the nearest decimal

Tags: numerics

If I have a bunch of numbers in a list `{1.435243523432,2434.2321321412,5.8239897,...}`, without multiplying everything by some power of ten and then dividing by that power later, is there an argument I can supply to `Round` that will round each number at the $k$th decimal place (or do nothing if the number isn't defined to that precision)?

For example, if we set $k = 3$ we'd like something like:

```
DecimalRound[{1.435243523432,2434.2321321412,5.8239897,...},3] = {1.435,2434.232,5.824,...}
```

Comment: `Round[1.23456,0.001]`

Comment: Have a look at the second argument of `Round`: [`Round[..., 10.^-k]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Round.html)

Comment: We used to be more tolerant of "easy" questions such as this and I think sometimes something is lost by closing too quickly.  This particular one is a *duplicate* and should have been closed as such, rather than "easily found in the documentation."  As can be seen from the original multiple people felt that the answers were valuable.